# Selenium and python : Page not loading (any browser)

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

As I was loading a webpage with selenium, it didn't load and after a while, even if I didn't tell it to, the window closed. I looked up on Internet and apparently, it has to deal with the version of geckodriver or selenium. I installed the last version of selenium available on pip, and I'm currently using geckodriver 0.31.0 (executable and scripts) and Firefox v100.

Can they work together or do I need to downgrade something ? (I installed the most recent version available for each one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can check from the official link  below*

[***GeckoDriver, Selenium and Firefox Browser compatibility chart***](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image]